# How to SET environment variables in "php.ini" or preferable ".user.ini"?

Tags: php

`php.ini` supports [using environment variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php), e.g. in paths, like can be seen in the following example. Additionally it by default supports the file [.user.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) to have at least some configs per directory of some web app, pretty much like is known for `.htaccess` files.

```
memory_limit = ${PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT}
```

**Is there some way to not only USE, but as well SET environment variables in `php.ini` or even `.user.ini`?** I didn't find anything like that, so "NO" might be a perfectly well answer. :-)

Reason is that I have a pretty legacy web app consisting of lots of individual PHP-files without some common PHP file included by all or some common controller to handle app-setup or alike. But some of those PHP-files invoke some shell commands which rely on different environment variables like `PATH` to find special apps. Would be great to have especially `.user.ini` to maintain all of those variables for all individual PHP-files at one place instead of e.g. needing to add those special apps to `PATH` of the system or the web server IIS used currently.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's legacy code you'd probably be better simply updating the code itself, rather than breaking big holes in your server's onion skins of defence. The words "legacy" and "shell commands" in close proximity to each other makes me feel nervous about keeping this status-quo ongoing.

Comment: Just set the environment variables in this way. Each command in a line. 
 `upload_max_filesize = 150M`
 `post_max_size = 150M`
`max_execution_time = 300`